# Using Variables in Replace() Method - Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, methods, replace

I am trying to replace the contents of the alt="" attribute in the tag.

The replacment text comes from  textarea input that is assigned to var alttext

The var oldtext contains  tags with placeholders for replacing, like:

```
<img alt="placeholder" scr="pic.jpg" />
```

The placeholder needs to be replaced the contents of var alttext.

So far I have tried:

```
function replacer() {
    var alttext = document.myform.alttext.value; 
    var oldtext = document.myform.oldtext.value;
    var replacedtext = oldtext.replace("placeholder", 'alttext' )
    document.myform.outputtext.value = replacedtext;        
}
```

But it does not work.

How can the alttext variable contents be used to replace the placeholder?

Thank you very much to everyone!

Comment: `oldtext.replace("placeholder", alttext)`.  Note the lack of quotes. `'alttext'` is a literal string, `alttext` is a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function replacer() {
   var alttext = document.myform.alttext.value; 
   var oldtext = document.myform.oldtext.value;
   var replacedtext = oldtext.replace("placeholder", alttext);
   document.myform.outputtext.value = replacedtext;        
}
```

you were trying to `replace` with quotes around your variable (alttext) making it a string literal